# Where are Endpoint.Behaviors and clientRuntime.MessageInspectors in .Net 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, .net-5

With all version of .Net until the 4.8, it was possible to easily catch all ingoing and outgoing traffic for SOAP services consumed with WCF for logging purpose, using `IEndpointBehavior / IClientMessageInspector`, as described here for example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest?view=netframework-4.8

I would like to know how I can restore this, or achieve the same purpose as before in .Net 5.0. I need to trace all SOAP exchanges in a log file, previously I just have to do :

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    _logger.Debug("Reply received: " + Environment.NewLine + "{0}", reply.ToString());
}
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    _logger.Debug("Sending request: " + Environment.NewLine + "{0}", request.ToString());
    return null;
}
```

To have it working, you need clientRuntime.MessageInspectors, and client.Endpoint.Behaviors to register the classes.

Despite I have registered nuget packages available for System.ServiceModel, and especially System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll these properties seems to not exist anymore.

Comment: Many features of wcf are not supported in .net 5, you can look at this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/supporting-the-community-with-wf-and-wcf-oss-projects/ . You can try grpc to replace wcf.

Comment: @TheobaldDu regarding grpc, I have to consume a legacy SOAP service so it does not seem relevant. Is there any solution to enable logging on service client proxies as they are handled in .Net 5.0 ? Maybe a free alternative to WCF or some kind of middleware to enable ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, these features are still existing and this seem to work like previously. The properties have just slightly changed.

`client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new LoggerEndpointBehavior(_logger));` became `client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new LoggerEndpointBehavior(_logger));`

And

`clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new LoggerClientMessageLoggerInspector(_logger));`
became `clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new LoggerClientMessageLoggerInspector(_logger));`

Everything else is like in the example in the first link.
I'm quite surprised to not have seen these suggestions by Intellisense when I was migrating, but it works now !